# Fetch company details on a click on button using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I created a table as company_list. This table consists of following fields

1)Company Name 2) Country 3) Vertical

So, lets assume there are 5 companies as following

Company Name: Water, Earth, Sun, Moon, Star

Countries: Water= UK, Earth=UK, Sun=Australia, Moon, =India, Star=Germany

Vertical:Water, Earth, Sun = WWF and Moon, Star=Social Welfare

First HTML is a select option to filter by

1st Country 2nd Vertical

So, if I chose UK country, vertical should auto select WWF (exclude AUS country company name)

Now, post this I have button to FETCH single COMPANY DETAILS first that matches the above condition.

Code, I have designed is not adding a filter and does fetch every company.

Kindly help with this.

1) index page

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","accounts");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM company_list";
$res= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$res1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
    <style media="screen">
    .navbar-inverse {
      background-color: #4a8cbb;
      border-color: #4a8cbb;
    }
    #row1{
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <select class="form-control">
            <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)):; ?>
              <option value="">SELECT COUNTRY</option>
                <option value=""><?php echo $row['country']; ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-header" id="row1">
      <select class="form-control">
        <?php while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)):; ?>
          <option value="">SELECT VERTICAL</option>
          <option value=""><?php echo $row1['vertical']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-header" id="row1">
      <button id="fetch_company" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block btn-huge">FETCH COMPANY DETAILS</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          Company Name:<span id="com_get_data"></span>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $("#fetch_company").click(function(){
    //alert("Working");
    count = count + 1;
    $("#com_get_data").load("get_data.php",{countNew:count});
  });
});
</script>

</html>
```

2)Get_data.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","accounts");

$countNew = $_POST['countNew'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM company_list LIMIT $countNew";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
  echo $row['company_name'];
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Check with  `$_GET["countNew"]` eaither use `$.ajax inside post` method

Answer (score 0):

Please check using `$.ajax`

> Jquery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $("#fetch_company").click(function(){
    //alert("Working");
    count = count + 1;   
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "get_data.php",
      data:{countNew:count},
      cache: false,
     success: function(result){
        $("#com_get_data").html(result);
     }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

> Php Code

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","accounts");

$countNew = $_POST['countNew'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM company_list LIMIT $countNew";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
  echo $row['company_name'];
}
}
else
{
  echo 'No result found';
}
 ?>
```

**Note: here you loop trough fetch data you need to add data in `string array` after that return data in `JSON`**

Please check here for more details [Click Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Appreciate your response, your code has the same function as  mine. How can we ensure fetch company belongs to selected country and vertical from the select option at the top. Thank you :)

Comment: You won't be based on `company id` get `company details`?

Comment: No success yet, still trying

Comment: What you want based on drop-down change display company details?